# convert an input value in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have this data in an input: `[16,57.35], [23,56.26], [34,54.57]`

and I want to turn it into an array

```
var data =$('#data').val();
var array = JSON.parse ("["+data+"]");
```

I'm having this error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token.

How I can fix it or I can convert the input value in array?

Comment: Works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sRb6x/)...

Comment: Please do a `console.log(data)` and post here what you are actually passing in.

Comment: Also check `data.length`, maybe there are some non-printing characters in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `eval` function:

```
var data = "123, 456, 789";
var array = eval("[" + data + "]");
```

You'll need to make sure that whatever you're inputting is valid JSON, but the above code will output an array for you. Hope it helps.

Comment: It actually *is* valid JSON, if he's wrapping it in `[]`, which I missed the first time around.

Comment: be careful, eval is considered harmful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: @MarcelSoleraAyala: You're welcome. Please make sure to mark the answer if you're satisfied.

Comment: @meagar - I put the data in at [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and it did not validate. Is there a less rigid interpretation of valid JSON that you are using?

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to explain? I hope this wasn't downvoted because of security concerns as that was not part of the question.

Comment: @Karl It validates, if you wrap it in `[]` as the question indicates: `[[16,57.35], [23,56.26], [34,54.57]]`

Comment: @meagar - Ah, I did not put the outer brackets. Thanks. :-)

Comment: @cfs Eval is not harmful in this particular use.

Comment: Of course there's no security concern (assuming the value was generated by the user). But `eval` is just bad practise, and for what it is used here `JSON.parse` would be better (and work just as well).

Comment: @JamesJohnson Regardless, you *should* be downvoted if you propose a solution that introduces security problems. Downvoting for security concerns is *completely* valid, whether or not they were explicitly mentioned in the question. However, in this case, such concerns are misguided and unfounded... That said, there is no reason to use `eval`, when the string *is* valid JSON. There is some other problem the question's author is ignoring by switch to `eval`.

Comment: @meagar: I agree that a downvote is valid when code *will* introduce a vulnerability. I disagree with downvoting based on precedent alone.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is working check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qqdKj/), you may need to include required jQuery library or check some thing else in the code causing it.

```
data = $('#txt1').val();
arr = JSON.parse ("["+data+"]");
console.log(arr);
```